# how to prevent ls to recursively list files in a subdir

Tags: linux, ls

I have, e.g.,  in the directory /etc/  files without extension and with extension

```
/etc/profile

/etc/profile.1

/etc/profile.2
```

and there is a directory given by the system containig some files:

```
/etc/profile.d/file1

/etc/profile.d/file2

/etc/profile.d/file3
```

In a script I would like to specify that ls lists all my profile* files but not the files in the directory which begins with the same name as my files.

If the dir name "/etc/profile.d/" will be listed is not important, but the files under this dir should not be listed.

This my wish is according to what the manpage says, that ls will only work recursively if the option "-R" is given.

I want to use ls because its sorting capabilities and because ls can show modification, access and creation times, etc.

Normaly I would use this command:

```
ls -la --time-style=long-iso /etc/profile*
```

but this not only shows my files, ls goes down into the directory /etc/profile.d and lists the files in this dir too.

I am interested in a general solution, not only for the given names in this example.

Regards

Anton_Wessel@t-online.de

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `-d` option? From `man ls`: *-d, --directory: list directories themselves, not their contents*

Comment: In a script, you probably don't want to be consuming the output of `ls`.  If you're just invoking it for user information, that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, please never use `ls` in a script, that is just asking for trouble. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985).

Comment: oh, yes:  ls -d /etc/profile*  makes what I wanted. I have this simple way overlooked, I am to old. Thanks, Regards Anton Wessel

Answer (score 2):

That's what `ls` is for, it `l`i`s`ts the contents of directories.

If passed files that are not directories, it lists those files instead. In order to get that behaviour for files of type *directory* as well, you need to pass the `-d` option in which case it lists the directory files themselves instead of their contents:

```
ls -l -d --time-style=long-iso /etc/profile*
```

I removed `-a` as it's only relevant when `ls` lists the contents of directories (as opposed to the directories themselves whose list is passed to `ls` by the shell after expanding the glob).

It's important to realise that above, it's not `ls` that generates the list of files, it's the shell that expands `/etc/profile*` to the list of matching files.

You almost always want to use `-d` when passing glob expansions to `ls`.

If using `zsh`, you can use its `stat` builtin to retrieve metadata from the files:

```
$ zmodload zsh/stat
$ stat -LF %FT%T.%N%z +mtime /etc/profile*
/etc/profile 2021-04-10T21:00:00.000000000+0100
/etc/profile.d 2022-09-22T17:26:49.109271759+0100
```

(here using a non-ambiguous date format).

Like `ls`'s output, that's still unprocessable in the face of file names with newline characters. You can however store the result in an array instead of displaying it:

```
stat -nA mtimes -LF %FT%T.%N%z +mtime /etc/profile*
```

And then loop on it with:

```
for file mtime ($mtimes) print -r -- ${(q+)file} was last modified on $mtime
```

Or

```
printf '%q was last modified on %s\n' $mtimes
```

Or call one `stat` per file, getting the result into an associative array for instance:

```
for file (/etc/profile*)
  stat -LH s -F %FT%T.%N%z -- $file &&
    print -r -- $file, $s[size] bytes big was last modified on $s[mtime]
```

Comment: Just to be specific, l -a is to list hidden files in the current or itemized directories.  Since you have specified a pattern which is not for hidden files, it is irrelevant to your pattern match.

Comment: @EricMarceau, No. Even in `ls -ld .*` it would be irrelevant, `-a` is for `ls` not to skip the hidden files in the directories whose contents **it** lists. With `-d`, it lists directories, not their contents.

Comment: Just addressing the specific usage of -a regarding the hidden files.  I did not say anything to contradict what you said regarding ls -d {pattern}* .

Comment: @EricMarceau, I'm just saying your *Since you have specified a pattern which is not for hidden files* is at best misleading. `-a` is irrelevant with `-d` whether the pattern matches hidden files or not.

Comment: "-a" is meant to display what ls does not display by default.  If the pattern is ".{pat}*", then that specification will display hidden files by default, overriding the non "-a" behaviour, so again, -a is irrelevant.  I don't understand why you take issue with my statement.

Answer (score -1):

How about `find`?

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name "profile*" -type f
```

Comment: You probably want the `ls` action to (quote) "show modification, access and creation times".  And you'll want to pipe to `sort`, since `find` produces unsorted output.

Comment: thanks. I thought on "find", but as I wrote, I would like to sick on "ls"; I have a way with ls, e.g.

Comment: la /etc/profile{,.[^d]*}

Comment: but that is specific for this example whe the directory has ".d" at end, it is not the general solution I am looking for.  regsrds Anton Wessel

Comment: thanks for all amswers. now it is done. Regards Anton Wessel

Comment: Regarding (I cite): "Yes, please never use ls in a script, that is just asking for trouble." -- I could'nt help but notice that I suffer since thirty years from the deficienties of ls, especially because it is so difficult to get directory listings with full path.

Comment: I have written uncountable many scripts to overcome the problems.

Comment: It would be time to make an improvement to ls. -- I am a too little man to achieve such, but perhaps a community can do.

Comment: Regards Anton Wessel.